# How to switch between light and dark mode in Material Design in XAML at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, darkmode, material-design-in-xaml

At runtime, I want to change my app's main theme (*which in this case is the light theme*) to the **dark theme**.

I'm using the C# programming language, with the WPF project template. And in this project.

I installed the `MaterialDesignThemes` library in my project, and by default I set it to the light theme.

```
<materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepPurple" SecondaryColor="DeepOrange" />
```

Now I want to create a mechanism that can change the theme from light to dark at application runtime.

Answer (score 1):

### We can divide this question into 2 occasions:

- Using only Code-Behind
- Using MVVM architecture

---

### Using only Code-Behind

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="GED.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GED.Views"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="DarkModeToggle"
                  Content="Dark Mode"
                  Checked="DarkModeToggle_Checked"/>
</Grid>
```

code-behind:

```
using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;
using System.Windows;

namespace GED.Views
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DarkModeToggle_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PaletteHelper palette = new PaletteHelper();

            ITheme theme = palette.GetTheme();

            if (DarkModeToggle.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                theme.SetBaseTheme(Theme.Dark);
            }
            else
            {
                theme.SetBaseTheme(Theme.Light);
            }
            palette.SetTheme(theme);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Using MVVM architecture

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="GED.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GED.Views" 
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:GED.ViewModels.Register"
    Title="MainWindow">

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainViewModelStackoverFlow/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="DarkModeToggle"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                  Command="{Binding DarkModeCommand}"
                  Checked="DarkModeToggle_Checked"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace GED.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private bool _isChecked;

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
            }
        }

        public ICommand DarkModeCommand { get; }

        public MainViewModelStackoverFlow()
        {
            DarkModeCommand = new ViewModelCommand(ExecuteDarkModeCommand);
        }

        private void ExecuteDarkModeCommand(object obj)
        {
            PaletteHelper palette = new PaletteHelper();

            ITheme theme = palette.GetTheme();

            if (IsChecked)
            {
                theme.SetBaseTheme(Theme.Dark);
            }
            else
            {
                theme.SetBaseTheme(Theme.Light);
            }
            palette.SetTheme(theme);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Note

You may have noticed that the **MainViewModel** is being inherited by the class called `ViewModelBase`, and also in the constructor of the class, an instance was created with the `ViewModelCommand` class.

For you to understand what these classes are, you need to know how to implement the MVVM architecture in your project.

In general it can be said that:

> ViewModelBase

- is a class inherited by all ViewModel that intend to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and this generates a event `void OnPropertyChange(string property);` which is responsible for notifying each change that is made to a property in the front-end (View).

> ViewModelCommand

- also known as `RelayCommand` is the class that handles each event in a generic way. When it comes to an event, in the remaining ViewModels, a ReadOnly property of type `ICommand` is used to serve as a trigger in View controls, as in the case of `<ToggleButton/>`.

Comment: Do you know if things change when using `<materialDesign:MahAppsBundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="Blue" SecondaryColor="Amber"/>`? Your code is exactly how I did it and it worked great when using the `BundledTheme` but using this option now with MahApps also, and the theme no longer switches. I can't find a new method or extension method that will update the theme.